# wordpress private domain for post

Tags: wordpress, url, post, dns, structure

i have built a wordpress site, the website is like an index of businesses.
each business has it's own post - and this post is like a minisite.
post example : http://www.ourevent.co.il/%D7%94%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A7/

now, i need to connect domain directly  to this post - and i need that the page structure remain the same.
i.e. mydomain.com/?page=gallery - will still work.

Thank's.